# Why is my gas oven no longer heating?

Tags: gas, oven

I have a Frigidaire gas wall oven that is no longer heating. It was working off and on the past couple of weeks but now is not heating at all.  All the electrical functions work and the igniter mechanism is turning on and heating (see picture), the gas is just not triggering.  The separate range/stove right next to it is working fine.  [I saw this video that says there's a thermal switch in the back](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3_Th93i6Yp0) but I wanted to see if others have ideas about this before I pull the oven out of the cabinet.

[image]
[image]

Comment: "I have a Frigidaire _electric_ wall oven" based on mentions of [tag:gas] and igniters, you really mean, "I have a Frigidaire _gas_ wall oven"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had that happen on my double oven Viking range. The igniter would glow, but not draw enough current to convince the gas valve to open. One oven had two igniters the other smaller oven had one.  All of them eventually failed.  I found higher quality after-market igniters and they have been working fine for many years now, lasting longer than the OEM ones.

Not sure if this applies to you, but it's close.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot say **for sure** with your particular oven, but I have experienced "partial electric ignitor failure" where it had basically cracked.

It would visually heat up, BUT evidently the safety circuit that decides if the gas solenoid opens (in that oven, may be common) depends on the current being drawn. Started with being flaky (would or would not work), got increasingly flakier, finally got stubborn and never worked. *Very similar to what you are describing...*

When the ignitor was actually removed (rather than just being looked at glowing brightly in place, and assumed to be fine as a result) the defect was obvious compared to the new ignitor, and the oven began working perfectly with the new ignitor.